# How do you modify the existing access scope of a Google Cloud Platform service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a service account, which is asssigned to my GCE instances and is listed as active, which I can verify by running `gcloud auth list` on any one of the instances. The service account currently has Google Cloud API access to a few services. What I'm wanting to do is update this access, so that the service account can read zone/record-set information from Google Cloud DNS.

I've looked at documentation around service accounts and editing their access as well as trying to edit the service account permissions in GCP, but I am not finding a direct way to add access to Google Cloud DNS specifically or Google Cloud Networking, which would be inclusive of DNS.  The service account permissions could be set as my own user account and assigned an owner/edit role, but I'd prefer to only grant the additional access the service account would need for Google Cloud DNS.

Any help or insight would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I believe eventually you will be able to do this using IAM permissions. At the moment I do not see the options to add Cloud DNS roles in the [IAM Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart). In order to authorize requests to Cloud DNS you must use one of the scopes describe in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/authorization).

i.e.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite
https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/authorization
```

If you are using the [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances), the scope has to be defined during the VM creation in the scope flag.

i.e.

```
gcloud compute --project "Myproject" instances create "instance-8" --zone "us-central1-f" --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --network "default" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" --scopes default="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite" --image "/debian-cloud/debian-8-jessie-v20161020" --boot-disk-size "10" --boot-disk-type "pd-standard" --boot-disk-device-name "instance-8"
```

If you associated the VM to a non-default service account during its creation, you can add [Editor or Owner](https://cloud.google.com/dns/overview) permissions to that account in the IAM Console. Nevertheless this might provide a wider scope that the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

1. In the Google Console, navigate to the "IAM & Admin" section
2. On the left nav, click "IAM"
3. Find your service account listed on the right.
4. Click the dropdown in the "Role(s)" column, to select a role for the service account.

[This page describes the IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam)

Comment: This does not change the scope of the service account, it has to be done at the instance/instance-template level I believe

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble accessing the Storage API, so I realized the problem was with the scopes. After doing some research, I found where to change it.

You must edit the "scope" for the current "Service Account", it has been set on VM creation and the default is pretty restrictive:

1. Go to Compute Engine / VM Instances
2. Locate the your VM and select it (check box)
3. Make sure it's Stopped (click on Stop otherwise)
4. Click on it's name
5. Click on "Edit"
6. Scroll down until you find "Service Account"
7. It should say "Default Scope", change to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs"

That's it!